# How to prevent client from changing critical HTML inputs?

Tags: javascript, php, html

As you probably know, you can use `Inspect element` in Chrome to modify the web page you're viewing and possibly mess up with `radio` values (or similar), which you're NOT meant to change, `required` inputs and much more.

For instance:

```
<input type='radio' name='example' id='abcd' value='abcd'>
<input type='radio' name='example' id='efgh' value='efgh'>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' required>
```

can be changed to

```
<input type='radio' name='example' id='OTHER_ID' value='OTHER_VALUE'>
<input type='radio' name='example' id='OTHER_ID2' value='OTHER_VALUE2'>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'>
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent the user to do changes in your `html` with `Inspect element`.

If users do this and something is not working on your website because of that change I think it's not your problem.

What you should make is do server side checks, because on server only you have access so nobody else will mess with your code there.

For this example you need to check on the server if you receive the `username`. If not return an error and don't save anything in DB.
Or check that the value you receive for the radio is accepted by you, and check that you receive all the keys that you want. Same with other fields, make sure you do all the checks on server side too, not only client-side.

Some code:

```
<?php

//Check if you receive a username
if(empty($_POST['username'])) {
  echo 'Username is empty'; exit;
}

//Check that the radio values are accepted.
if(!in_array($_POST['example'], ['abcd', 'efgh'])){
   echo 'Example radio has some bad values'; exit;
}
```

You need to adjust the code depends what's mandatory and what is not for users to add and where they can type anything or some specific type.

Comment: So you're saying I should validate everything with, for example, isset()?

Comment: yes, you cant rely on the front-end, thats why you need to validate on the back-end always.

Comment: @sgrontflix Add some example of PHP checks. You can check in many ways that you receive something that you need.